# Show clock/time increment from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, timer

I tried to show/increment the only time(Hours, Minutes and Seconds) like a timer from getting server side, but it's not working for me.

For this I tried below code.

Can you please help me to run the specified time (Server Time) to run as Timer.

What I have tried:

c#

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "close", "OnRunnTimer("+0.21023+");", true);
```

// JS COde

```
//Server time I am sending serverTimeP = 0.21023

function OnRunnTimer(timeP) { 
            setInterval(function () { runJSTimer(timeP); }, 1000);
        }

 function runJSTimer(serverTimeP) {

var d = new Date();
              
             d.setHours(serverTimeP);             
            
 
             var hours = d.getHours();
             var min = d.getMinutes();
             var sec = d.getSeconds();
 
             lblJsTimer.SetText(hours + ":" + min + ":" + sec);

}
```

[image]
Can you please help on this.

Comment: are you setting timeP or serverTimeP?  setting serverTimeP outside the runJSTimer function won't affect the value of serverTimeP inside the function.

Comment: @BlackICE From Server side passing the value `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "close", "OnRunnTimer("+0.21023+");", true);` see updated thread

Comment: I would suggest, if you have an IDE capable of it, putting breakpoints in the OnRunnTimer, and in the runJSTimer functions to see if they're even being called, if you don't have an IDE that can do that, add some console.log statements instead, just don't forget to remove them when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood, but this is my example of solution to what I think to be your issue.

```html
<body>
    <h2 id="timeLabel">Time Label!</h2>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var hours = 0;
        var min = 0;
        var sec = 0;
        var serverTime = '2021-02-17T14:34:14.426Z'; // server time example in ISO format

        var refreshTimeLabel = function(){
            document.getElementById("timeLabel").innerHTML = hours + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
        }

        var refreshVariables = function () {
            var serverTimeDate = new Date(serverTime);
            var updatedServerTimeInMilliseconds = serverTimeDate.getTime() + (1000);
            var updatedServerTimeDate = new Date(updatedServerTimeInMilliseconds);

            serverTime = updatedServerTimeDate.toISOString();
            hours = updatedServerTimeDate.getHours();
            min = updatedServerTimeDate.getMinutes();
            sec = updatedServerTimeDate.getSeconds();
        }

        var startTimer = function() { 
            setInterval(function () { 
                refreshVariables();
                refreshTimeLabel();
            }, 1000);
        }

        startTimer();
    </script>
</body>
```

### Variant for multiple rows

```html
<body>
    <h2 id="timeLabel">Time Label!</h2>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var serverTimes = ['2021-02-17T16:34:45.426Z', '2021-02-17T14:54:14.426Z', '2021-02-17T14:00:00.426Z']; // server time array example in ISO format
        
        var refreshServerTimeByIndex = function (index) {
            var serverTime = serverTimes[index];
            var serverTimeDate = new Date(serverTime);
            var updatedServerTimeInMilliseconds = serverTimeDate.getTime() + (1000);
            var updatedServerTimeDate = new Date(updatedServerTimeInMilliseconds);

            serverTimes[index] = updatedServerTimeDate.toISOString();
        }

        var refreshServerTimes = function(){
            var i;
            for(i = 0; i < serverTimes.length; i++){
                refreshServerTimeByIndex(i);
            }
        }

        var getTimeTextByDateISO = function(dataISO){
            var date = new Date(dataISO);
            var hours = date.getHours();
            var min = date.getMinutes();
            var sec = date.getSeconds();
            return hours + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
        }

        var refreshTimeLabel = function(){
            var textLabel = "";
            var i;
            for(i = 0; i < serverTimes.length; i++){
                textLabel += " | " + getTimeTextByDateISO(serverTimes[i]);
            }

            document.getElementById("timeLabel").innerHTML = textLabel;
        }

        var startTimer = function() { 
            setInterval(function () { 
                refreshServerTimes();
                refreshTimeLabel();
            }, 1000);
        }

        startTimer();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, It's working when there is only static time. In my Fun. the timer value is variant for multiple rows from ASPxGridView. See my updated thread.

Comment: I think this is just a matter of adapting the code to work with various values. Doesn't it? Or... What do you imagine as input and output?

Comment: Thank you, Samir. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: @MagentoNav If I solved your problem, set my answer as the correct solution. Please :)

Comment: it's a correct. But my requirement the `serverTimes` is not a static it's a dynamic. Passing the value from server side. Can we have example on my requirement?